# LOWA renegade insole is sliding

Tags: hiking, climbing, trekking, boots, shoes

I used my Lowa renegade for 10 years and I bought a new pair. On the first 7km the insoles are sliding back. I tried again, same problem... I just realised even with hands I can slide the insoles up and down. I went to the shop and it's happening with another pair in the same size (46,5)... strangely it's not sliding in a pair with size 41 for example... And I can't move it in my old boots... Any suggestions? Quite bad for 200€...

Comment: What did the shop say about returning as faulty?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: They offered me a new insole or glueing the old insole in... I am not sure if it will help at all... Definitely gluing is not a right solution... :/